# How to turn on change keyboard light on change lang

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, ubuntu-gnome, xset

how to cancel turn on/off keyboard light when i change language on ubuntu 20.04?

i configured my custom turn on and turn off by script

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -f /tmp/keyboard_light ]; then
xset -led 3 && rm /tmp/keyboard_light
else
xset led 3 && touch /tmp/keyboard_light
fi
```

but when i change lang from tray or "Super+Space" keyboard light changed too

Answer (score 0):

1)`gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options`
see `['grp_led:scroll']`

2. `setxkbmap -layout 'us,ru' -option ''` - turn off change scroll indicator on change lang
3. `xmodmap -pm` and see

`shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e) lock        Caps_Lock (0x42) control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_R (0x69) mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Alt_R (0x6c),  Meta_L (0xcd) mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d) mod3       mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf) mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)`

mod3  is empty

4. `xmodmap -e 'add mod3 = Scroll_Lock'`

and my keyboard light is toggle on press Scroll Lock button